# Adding confirm password field into default Cognito UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, attributes, amazon-cognito, password-confirmation, aws-userpools

I have a Cognito User pool instance and I need to add a confirm password field in the signup form of Hosted Ui. However, I can't specify it anywhere in the userpool configuration. Does anyone know how to add a confirm password field?

(Note: I do not want to write my own customised login, I want to use Cognito's Hosted UI)

Comment: how much did you try with plain text its difficult to answer it